# AndroidViewClient View Checkbox isChecked()

Tags: android, python-2.7, mobile, androidviewclient

I can use Culebra to touch the checkbox of Mobile data, make a checking True or False by calling `checkbox_id.isChecked()`, everything is working fine. But I can't find the method `isChecked()` in the script `ViewClient.py`, where does this method come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at `View.__getattr__()`, you'll see

```
   if self.map.has_key(name):
        ...
   elif name.startswith('is'):
        # try removing 'is' prefix
        if DEBUG_GETATTR:
            print >> sys.stderr, "    __getattr__: trying without 'is' prefix"
        suffix = name[2:].lower()
        if self.map.has_key(suffix):
            r = self.map[suffix]
        else:
            # Default behavior
            raise AttributeError, name
```

So, when you invoke `isChecked()` on a `View` instance, 'is' prefix is removed and the remaining string is converted to lowercase and then `self.map` is checked to verify if it contains such key.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I didn't realize it was an attribute matter.

Comment: it's done, and for the others questions you have answered too, sorry my bad, I have to learn how to use stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thanks, this keeps the site well organized.